# Does arcpy.GetParameterAsText() have a data type?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, python-script-tool

```
import arcpy 
# Retrieve input parameters
inX = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
inY = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
inDescription = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

incidentsFC = "C:/Data/Yakima/Incidents.shp"
descriptionField = "DESCR"

# Make a tuple of fields to update
fieldsToUpdate = ("SHAPE@XY", descriptionField)

# Create the insert cursor
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(incidentsFC, fieldsToUpdate) as cursor:
    # Insert the row providing a tuple of affected attributes
    cursor.insertRow(((float(inX),float(inY)), inDescription))
```

I came across this script tool in an online course which shows an example for using the Insert Cursor where we insert a row in a point shapefile. I couldn't understand something here. Do we somehow specify what 'type' of input we will provide when we use `GetParameterAsText()`?

If yes, then why do we need to specify again in the last line that the coordinates given earlier are float type?

Can't we just write `cursor.insertRow((inX, inY), inDescription)` and if No, then how does Python understand the input in the variable `inDescription` is a string/text without using the double quotes anywhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the name GetParameterAsText() indicates, or the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000047000000) states, the value will be converted to *text*, or like we call it: a *string*.

```
Gets the specified parameter as a **text** string by its index position from the list of parameters.
```

So, if the user enteres coordinates, such as *35.5432* then the tool would get understand those as *'35.5432'*, a string. This is, however, not necessarily what we want, so, in this case, we would convert that string back to a number. As we are interested in the decimals we have to convert it to a *float* (not an integer, as it would chop off the decimals), and use *float()*.

Note that you could also have converted right when getting the parameters:

```
inX = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0))
```

In my opinion that makes the code easier to read, and less cluttered later on.

The important part with *GetParameterAsText()* is what you define in ArcGIS, when you build the tool. Here the more important, ArcGIS-internal data type, is defined. It can be daunting at first, and sometimes one has to try multiple times until finding the correct type. The interface looks like this (sorry, German interface!):

[image]

But the bottom line is, it would arrive in your Python as **text**, so sometimes conversions are necessary, such as the *float()* in this case!

Answer (score 4):

To respect the type of input set on a Python script tool's dialog you would need to use arcpy.GetParameter().

By using arcpy.GetParameterAsText() my understanding is that whatever is ingested has its data type converted to a string.

It appears that `float` is being used here to convert those strings into floating point numbers.