# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x_degree'

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, string, double

I want to create a decimal degree (dd) field from degree minute seconds (DMS) as a script tool.

The CSV looks like this.

[image]

My code looks like this:

```py
import arcpy
inTable = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
x_deg = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))
x_min = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2))
x_sec = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3))
y_deg = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4))
y_min = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5))
y_sec = float(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(6))
DD_X = (x_sec/3600) + (x_min/60)+ x_deg
DD_Y = (y_sec/3600) + (y_min/60)+ y_deg
arcpy.AddField_management(inTable, DD_X, "DOUBLE", 20, 10)
arcpy.AddField_management(inTable, DD_Y, "DOUBLE", 20, 10)
```

I keep getting an error message:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'x_degree'

I feel like this should be straightforward, but perhaps I'm over simplifying.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The value from your second parameter can't be converted to a float (ex: `"abc"`). There's not enough information here to know why. Remove the the `float ()` from the line of code and print out it's value (`arcpy.AddMessage (x_deg)`) to see if it's what you think it should be.

Comment: thx for your reply.  I put the AddMessage and did not see any information in the geoprocessing history.  Could it be the headers?  I'm really new to Python (obviously) so I'm a bit lost.  .

Comment: Where are you running your code? Is it a stand-alone script? `arcpy.GetParameterAsText` only works in custom tools and models in modelbuilder.

Comment: Yes a custom tool

Comment: A screenshot of your custom tool with your seven inputs and example values in each would be helpful.

Comment: I added a pic of the inputs, which is based on the pic of the csv I attached previously.

Comment: Your inputs are field names. To access their values you'll need to use a cursor.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132659/does-arcpy-getparameterastext-have-a-data-type

Comment: I was trying to change the inputs to a float, according to the above link.

Comment: The string `x_degree` can't be converted to a float because it contains non-numeric characters (x, _, d, e, etc.)

Comment: That answer refers to numeric input, not strings

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Note that you can't add a field to a csv with `arcpy.AddField_management`.

Comment: Yeah, I turned it into a dbf.  Thx

Comment: Is this resolved?  If so, please write up an answer and accept it.